# How to execute Macro code inside a module from a worksheet_change event

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of raw data on sheet 1 of my workbook. On sheet 2 I use formulas to pull in some of that data from sheet 1.

Using a Macro that I created and posted in Module 1 I want to hide any rows that do not contain specific data. I am able to execute the macro directly when I need to via Run>Run Sub/Userform. It works perfectly.

However, I would prefer it to run when it needs to update via a worksheet_change event in the background whenever an edit is made to sheet 1. Because I am making edits on sheet 1 but want the change to execute the macro on sheet 2 I understand that the worksheet_change event has to be placed in "This Worksheet" as opposed to the specific sheet.

Here's the macro code

```
Sub HideRows()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do While Not Cells(i, 5) = ""
    If Cells(i, 5).Value = 0 Then
        Rows(CStr(i) + ":" + CStr(i)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Cells(i, 5).Value <> 0 And Rows(CStr(i) + ":" + CStr(i)).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        Rows(CStr(i) + ":" + CStr(i)).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Run directly the code above does what I need. The code I am using below to execute this via a worksheet_change event doesn't work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Me.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Call HideRows
    End With
End Sub
```

Any help with how to execute the macro using worksheet_change would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this the same as your prev [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542758/hide-unhide-cells-with-empty-rows-on-worksheet-change)

Comment: Not really, that was about the code needed to hide/unhide rows. This is about how to execute that. There is some overlap though but I didn't post any code in that question.

Comment: in your `HideRows` macro, fully qualify the cells. For example `Sheet2.Cells(i, 5).Value`

Comment: Also where is the change happening in Sheet 1? Which Cell or Column?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changes are made on sheet 1, column A. The formulas that pull that data into sheet 2 are in column E. Column E is where the HideRows macro is looking for a "0".

Comment: I have posted an answer. You may have to refresh the page to see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few points worth noting

1. The problem is that you are not fully qualifying the cells so when the `HideRows` macro is called, even though you have used `With Me.Worksheets("Sheet2")` it is still referring to the current sheet which is `Sheet1`. Fully qualify your range objects as shown below. Notice the `Dots` before them?
2. If the changes are happening in Col `A` of `Sheet1` then trap that else your macro will run for any change in `Sheet1` thereby making your workbook slow.
3. You do not need to keep the macro in a module. You can put the entire code in `Sheet1` as shown below
4. Also `Rows(CStr(i) + ":" + CStr(i))` can be written as `Rows(i)`
5. When working with rows in Excel it is always advisable to declare them as `Long` and not `Integer`. Post `Excel2007` the number of rows have increased and the `Integer` variable may not be able to accommodate that.

Is this what you are trying? Put this code in Sheet code area of `Sheet1`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long, lRow As Long

    '~~> Check of the change is happening in Col 1
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        With Worksheets("Sheet2")
            lRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 1 To lRow
                If .Cells(i, 5).Value = 0 Then
                    .Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                ElseIf .Cells(i, 5).Value <> 0 And .Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
                    .Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I have posted this code into the code area of Sheet 1 but am seeing the 0 in the relevant cell but the row is not being hidden. I will check to make sure I'm not doing something wrong.

Comment: BTW you can change `If .Cells(i, 5).Value = 0 Then` to `If .Cells(i, 5).Value = 0  And .Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've created a whole new sheet and still can't get it to hide the relevant row. Not sure what I am doing wrong but I'll keep trying...

Comment: Ok do this... `1` Ensure that the code is pasted in the "Sheet1" code area `2` I hope you have got the sheet names correct? `3` In the Immediate window of VBE, type this `Application.Enableevents=true`

Comment: Wow, 1 and 2 were fine but it still didn't work. I did 3 and it worked. I have plenty of other macros in other sheets working fine without #3 so I need to do some reading about that, haha.

Comment: Many, many thanks for your time and effort. You're a credit to this community!!

Comment: Glad to be of help :) You may have switched it off in some other macro by mistake and forgot to switch it on. If you would have given a serious thought to what I suggested in the first comment of your previous question then you wouldn't have faced this problem ;) There is a link that I gave you to read in that comment ;)

Comment: Here is the [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542758/hide-unhide-cells-with-empty-rows-on-worksheet-change) again :)